# Flagging as Low Quality should add the post to the review queue

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review-system

In [How to handle crankery on MathOverflow 2.0?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/62/how-to-handle-crankery-on-mathoverlow-2-0) Andy Putman pointed out that he flagged a post as low quality, but it never reached the low quality review queue.

I feel that in order to effectively handle cranks, or generally low quality posts, whenever a user (with sufficient reputation, maybe 1k?) flags a post as low quality it should be immediately added to the review queue.

I feel that this would be a good feature, at least on MathOverflow, but probably on MSE as well (I don't use other sites across the SE networks, so I can't say much else).

Comment: I should point out, in case some of the new users on the SE systems are unaware, that it is perfectly fine to post network-wide software requests on meta sites of particular sites (rather than just meta.SO). The developers are well aware to this, and usually respond within reasonable time.

Comment: Thanks Asaf!!!!

Comment: @Andy: Anything to procrastinate work! :-P

Comment: Usually it's better to post on MSO, though :) This is a great idea.

Comment: @Manishearth: I don't like to accumulate accounts over the SE networks. I refuse to open any further than MSE (and MO which was "forced into linkage" due to the migration). Since developers do follow site metas it's fine. Feel free to copy-paste this to MSO.

Comment: @AsafKaragila no probs. :) re:copypaste: Nah, IIRC cross posting is discouraged.

Comment: For that matter, I feel that NAA flags should also be piped to the LQ queues :)

Comment: @Manishearth: Sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

See [Can flags send a post into the Low Quality Posts review queue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181165/can-flags-send-a-post-into-the-low-quality-posts-review-queue)