# Should delete votes add a post to the low quality posts review queue?

Tags: discussion

Presently, [unlike "Very Low Quality" flags](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/147/flagging-as-low-quality-should-add-the-post-to-the-review-queue), delete votes do not add
a post to the "Low Quality Posts" review queue. -- Should they?